# Run Scrapy -o JSON From Separate Script

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, scrapy

I have a python3 script in which I call 2 scrapy spiders to output a JSON file at some point in the code.
At the moment I'm doing this by running a bat script as per below:

`subprocess.call(["scrapy.bat"])`

Bat Script:

```
cd C:\Python\crawler\crawler\spiders
scrapy crawl project1 -o project1.json
scrapy crawl project2 -o project2.json
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do the exact the same thing within the python script without using a bat script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to run a spider from a separate python Script:

In my python file I can import the spider and run it using `CrawlerProcess`

Example: Let's say that I have my `RedditSpider` in another Python file called `test_reddit.py` in the same directory as my python script. I just need to add the code below to run the spider:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

from test_reddit import RedditSpider

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_URI': 'results.json'
    })
    c.crawl(RedditSpider)
    c.start()
```

There's some info on this in Scrapy's docs: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script

Comment: Ahh makes sense! How would I output the results to a JSON file though?

Comment: add `FEED_FORMAT` and `FEED_URI` to the settings given to `CrawlerProcess`.
I've updated the answer